# VB.NET: order dictionary alphabetically

Tags: vb.net, linq, sorting, dictionary

I have a Dictinary(Of String, Item) and I'm trying to sort it into alphabetical order by the item name. I don't want to use a sorted dictinary and without it, I've having zero luck. Linq is not my strong point...

```
Public Class Item
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property size As String
    Public Property price As Decimal
    Public Property timeMachine As Boolean
End Class
```

Comment: You should implement Isortable and some other interfaces or use SortedDictionary or other list classes that implements those interfaces.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a SortedDictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)` is inherently an unordered type.  There is no way to sort one.   Try using `SortedDictionary(Of TKey, TValue)` instead.

```
Dim map = new SortedDictionary(Of String, Item)()
```

Answer (score 0):

(1) Get the list of keys, (2) sort the keys and (3) fetch dictionary's values according to the sorted keys

```
Dim keys As List(Of String) = dictionary.Keys.ToList
keys.Sort()

For Each str As String In Keys
  Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", str, dictionary.Item(str))
Next
```